# hibernate inheritance save child after parent

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, inheritance, spring-data-jpa

I'm using **[Joined Hibernate Inheritance Mapping](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-inheritance#joined-table)** in my entity stucture in this way:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name= "app_user")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    //some other fields
}



@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name= "app_customer")
public class Customer extends User {
    //some other fields
}
```

I want to to **save a user first, and after a while save a customer in another api and map that customer to first user**. So I try to save a new customer with **existing user id** in this way:

```
User user = ... //find already saved user
Customer customer = new Customer();
customer.setId(user.getId());
...
customerRepository.save()
```

But, hibernate generates customer **with new generated id(rather than fixed passed id) and also generates a new user.** Here is my question: **How can I save a child after its parent?** or **Is there anyway to save child without saving parent again?**

Comment: Don't use inheritance. Databases don't support inheritance. Maybe add a field user_id for Customer.

Comment: @yuri777 The problem is not related to database. We don't need inheritance in db layer.

Comment: Of course the problem is not in database. You created 2 tables in database: app_user and app_customer. And database doesn't contains information about inheritance. It is just 2 tables with the same fields (or almost same). When you create and save new User you add new record to the table app_user.  When you create and save new Customer you create new record to the table app_customer. And this records have different ID which generated automatic.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change second entity:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name= "app_customer")
public class Customer{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    User user;

    //some other fields
}
```